# TorchVision using pretrained weights for entire model vs backbone

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, retinanet

TorchVision Detection models have a `weights` and a `weights_backbone` parameter. Does using pretrained `weights` imply that the model uses pretrained `weights_backbone` under the hood? I am training a RetinaNet model and um unsure which of the two options I should use and what the differences are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is pretty simple: you can either choose to do transfer learning on the backbone only or on the whole network.

RetinaNet from Torchvision has a Resnet50 backbone. You should be able to do both of:

- `retinanet_resnet50_fpn(weights=RetinaNet_ResNet50_FPN_Weights.COCO_V1)`
- `retinanet_resnet50_fpn(backbone_weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)`

As implied by their names, the backbone weights are different. The former were trained on COCO (object detection) while the later were trained on ImageNet (classification).

To answer your question, pretrained `weights` implies that the whole network, including backbone weights, are initialized. However, I don't think that it calls `backbone_weights` under the hood.